# I am trying to write a method that sums up adjacent cells in array and fills the position in a second array with the value obtained

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am pretty new to java and am wondering how I would take a n x n array with these values and sum the surrounding values and then insert it into secondArray perhaps using a for loop? I appreciate the help.

firstArray:

1    1    0    1    0    1

1    0    1    0    1    0

1    1    0    0    1    1

1    1    0    0    1    1

0    0    0    1    1    0

secondArray:

2    3    3    2    3    1

4    6    3    3    4    4

4    5    3    4    4    4

3    3    3    4    5    4

2    2    2    2    3    3

Comment: Well if you post your code we can point out what doesn't work. Questions with code are more likely to be answered than those that ask people to do something for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the mechanics (added one last row to the matrix as you said the matrix is NxN):

```
int[][] matrix = new int[][]{
        { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};

int[][] result = new int[ matrix.length ][ matrix.length ];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        result[ i ][ j ] = sumOfSurrounding( matrix, i, j );
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        System.out.print( result[ i ][ j ] + " " );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now, you just have to implement the `static int sumOfSurrounding( int[][] matrix, int i, int j )` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just updated the post. Although I keep getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to run.

Comment: the above code runs without errors... your implementation of `sumOfSurrounding` must check the bounds of the array before trying to access or write to the array. It's not that hard.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: if your array is this: `int[] array = new int[] { 1 };`, then this works: `array[0]` but this will throw an Exception: `array[1]` because the array only has the `0` index, not the `1` index. So, you normally check first how big the array is, like this: `if (index >= 0 && index < array.length) { array[index]; }` where `index` is some variable integer.